# objective-c I can't understand why using of sprintf lead program to crash

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4.5

```
-(void)InitWithPwd:(char *)pPwd
{

    char szResult[17];


    //generate md5 checksum
    CC_MD5(pPwd, strlen(pPwd),&szResult[0]);
    szResult[16] = 0;

    m_csPasswordHash[0]=0;


    for(int i = 0;i < 16;i++) 
    {

        char sz[3] = {'\0'};
        //crash in blow row. The first pass is ok. The third pass crash. 
        //I can't understand.
        sprintf(&sz[0],"%2.2x",szResult[i]);
        strcat(m_csPasswordHash,sz);
    }

    m_csPasswordHash[32] = 0;
    printf("pass:%s\n",m_csPasswordHash);
    m_ucPacketType = 1;

}
```

I want to get the md5 of the password.  But above code crash again and again. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your buffer (`sz`) is too small, causing `sprintf()` to generate a buffer overflow which leads to undefined behavior, in your case a crash.

Note that `szResult[1]` might be a negative value when viewed as an `int` (which happens when passing a `char`-type value to `sprintf()`), which can cause `sprintf()` to disregard your field width and precision directives in order to format the full value.

[Here is an example showing this problem](http://ideone.com/QNum5x). The example code is written in C, but that shouldn't matter for this case.

This solves the problem by making sure the incoming data is considered unsigned:

```
sprintf(sz, "%02x", (unsigned char) szResult[i]);
```

Comment: You mean the size of sz?   3 byte is not enough for one byte like "0x1d"?

Comment: @penghao Not when sign extension happens, no. See the linked-to code example.

Comment: Yes you are right.  The point is "(unsigned char)". You are so experienced and very impressive.